# Show respective tab content on click with vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, tabs

I've been trying to build a basic tab system with vanilla JS.
I'm using a for loop in order to add the class **active** when a tab is clicked. That's working fine but now I need to display the respective tab-content element underneath.
I've tried using the same approach such as by adding the following to the switchClass function:
**tabContents.classList.remove("show-content");**
**tabContents.classList.add("show-content");**

But that didn't work as expected.

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
const tabContents = document.querySelector(".tab-content");

for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  const tab = tabs[i];
  tab.addEventListener("click", switchClass);
}

function switchClass(e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    const tab = tabs[i];
    tab.classList.remove("active");
    tabContents.classList.remove("show");
  }

  e.target.classList.add("active");
  tabContents.classList.add("show");
}
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tab {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.show-content {
  display: block;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="tab active">Tab 1</li>
  <li class="tab">Tab 2</li>
  <li class="tab">Tab 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content show-content">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <p>Phasellus aliquam orci neque, non varius quam gravida vel.</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <p>
    Vivamus iaculis est in sapien congue, ac condimentum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the index of the clicked tab, and then use that to display the content at the same index.

1. Use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector` (this will only select one element)
2. The class is named `show-content` not `show`.
3. Remove the `show-content` class within the for loop.
4. Find the index of the clicked element within its parent.
5. Use this index to select the corresponding content.

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
const tabContents = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-content");

for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  const tab = tabs[i];
  tab.addEventListener("click", switchClass);
}

function switchClass(e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    const tab = tabs[i];
    tab.classList.remove("active");
    tabContents[i].classList.remove("show-content");
  }
  
  const index = Array.prototype.slice.call(e.target.parentElement.children).indexOf(e.target)

  e.target.classList.add("active");
  tabContents[index].classList.add("show-content");
}
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tab {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.show-content {
  display: block;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="tab active">Tab 1</li>
  <li class="tab">Tab 2</li>
  <li class="tab">Tab 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content show-content">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <p>Phasellus aliquam orci neque, non varius quam gravida vel.</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <p>
    Vivamus iaculis est in sapien congue, ac condimentum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
const contents = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-content");

tabs.forEach(tab => tab.addEventListener("click", function() {
  tabs.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove("active"));
  contents.forEach(c => c.classList.remove("show-content"));

  const contentId = this.dataset.content;

  this.classList.add("active");

  document.querySelector(`.tab-content[data-content="${contentId}"]`).classList.add("show-content");
}));
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tab {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.show-content {
  display: block;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="tab active" data-content="1">Tab 1</li>
  <li class="tab" data-content="2">Tab 2</li>
  <li class="tab" data-content="3">Tab 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content show-content" data-content="1">
  <p>
    1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="tab-content" data-content="3">
  <p>3. Phasellus aliquam orci neque, non varius quam gravida vel.</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-content" data-content="2">
  <p>
    2. Vivamus iaculis est in sapien congue, ac condimentum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use event delegation an get the current number of the clicked tab

```
const ulAllTabs      = document.querySelector('ul#all-tabs')
  ,   ulAllTabsLi    = ulAllTabs.querySelectorAll('li')
  ,   AllContentsDiv = document.querySelectorAll('#all-contents > div')
  ;
ulAllTabs.onclick=e=>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('li')) return // ignore others clicks outside

  ulAllTabsLi.forEach( (li,i) => {
    if (e.target===li) {
      li.classList.add('active' )
      AllContentsDiv[i].classList.add('active' )
      }
    else {
      li.classList.remove('active' )
      AllContentsDiv[i].classList.remove('active' )
      }
    })
  }
```

I have added a `<section>` to group all divs (more clear at my eyes...)

```js
const ulAllTabs      = document.querySelector('ul#all-tabs')
  ,   ulAllTabsLi    = ulAllTabs.querySelectorAll('li')
  ,   AllContentsDiv = document.querySelectorAll('#all-contents > div')
  ;
ulAllTabs.onclick=e=>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('li')) return // ignore others clicks outside

  ulAllTabsLi.forEach((li,i)=>
    {
    if (e.target===li)
      {
      li.classList.add('active' )
      AllContentsDiv[i].classList.add('active' )
      }
    else
      {
      li.classList.remove('active' )
      AllContentsDiv[i].classList.remove('active' )
      }
    })
  }
```

```css
ul#all-tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
ul#all-tabs > li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
ul#all-tabs > li.active {
  background: lightgrey;
  }
section#all-contents > div {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  }
section#all-contents > div.active {
  display: block;
  background: lightgray;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="all-tabs">
  <li class="active">Tab 1</li>
  <li class="">Tab 2</li>
  <li class="">Tab 3</li>
</ul>
<section id="all-contents">
  <div class="active">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <p>Phasellus aliquam orci neque, non varius quam gravida vel.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <p>
      Vivamus iaculis est in sapien congue, ac condimentum.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

you can also use a data attribute to link your tabs with your divs

```
const ulAllTabs    = document.querySelector('ul#all-tabs')
  ,   tabs_and_Div = [...ulAllTabs.querySelectorAll('li')].reduce((res,eTab)=>
        {
        res.push( { tab:eTab, div: document.querySelector(`div.tab-content[data-ref="${eTab.dataset.ref}"]`)} )
        return res
        },[])
  ;
ulAllTabs.onclick=e=>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('li'))   return // ignore others clicks outsides 

  tabs_and_Div.forEach(tbDv=> {
    if (e.target===tbDv.tab) {
      tbDv.tab.classList.add('active')
      tbDv.div.classList.add('show-content')
      }
    else {
      tbDv.tab.classList.remove('active')
      tbDv.div.classList.remove('show-content')
      }
    })
  }
```

```js
const ulAllTabs    = document.querySelector('ul#all-tabs')
  ,   tabs_and_Div = [...ulAllTabs.querySelectorAll('li')].reduce((res,eTab)=>
        {
        res.push( { tab:eTab, div: document.querySelector(`div.tab-content[data-ref="${eTab.dataset.ref}"]`)} )
        return res
        },[])
  ;
ulAllTabs.onclick=e=>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('li'))   return // ignore others clicks outsides 

  tabs_and_Div.forEach(tbDv=> {
    if (e.target===tbDv.tab) {
      tbDv.tab.classList.add('active')
      tbDv.div.classList.add('show-content')
      }
    else {
      tbDv.tab.classList.remove('active')
      tbDv.div.classList.remove('show-content')
      }
    })
  }
```

```css
ul#all-tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
ul#all-tabs > li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
ul#all-tabs > li.active {
  background: lightgrey;
  }
.tab-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  }
.show-content {
  display: block;
  background: lightgray;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="all-tabs">
  <li data-ref="1" class="active"> Tab 1</li>
  <li data-ref="2" > Tab 2</li>
  <li data-ref="3" > Tab 3</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content show-content" data-ref="1">
  <p>
    1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="tab-content" data-ref="3">
  <p>3. Phasellus aliquam orci neque, non varius quam gravida vel.</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-content" data-ref="2">
  <p>
    2. Vivamus iaculis est in sapien congue, ac condimentum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tabContents variable will be an array of elements. So you will need to access the specific element using the relevant index:

```
tabContents[0].classList.add("show-contents");
```